# PuTTY Fatal Error: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: ssh, putty, cpanel

I am attempting to connect to our server via SSH using PuTTY and receive this error immediately after entering user credentials: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

I used to be able to do this successfully, so something must have changed on the server end (cPanel) but I cannot determine what. Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

[Edited to add log file]

```
Authenticated to ([IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Mon May  4 19:47:44 2020 from IP-SOURCE
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
Last login: Mon May  4 19:47:44 2020 from IP-SOURCE
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
Connection to IP closed.
Transferred: sent 2288, received 2672 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4577.6, received 5345.9
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The message PuTTY fails with is

> Remote side sent SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO after USERAUTH_SUCCESS

Based on the source code at https://github.com/github/putty/blob/master/sshverstring.c#L526, PuTTY knows of some servers that *"We believe remote version has SSH-2 rekey bug"*. The detection is done based on a version identification string sent by the server to the client during the initial handshake.

The SSH-2 rekey bug is documented:

- [https://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-bug-rekey](https://tartarus.org/%7Esimon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-bug-rekey)

PuTTY's list cannot possibly be comprehensive, and I believe what's happening is that some servers that do have *"the SSH-2 rekey bug"* are not on PuTTY's list of known buggy servers.

In my case this failure happens on Ubuntu 16 ("OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10"), but not older CentOS 6 ("OpenSSH_5.3"). I have done some testing to constrain the newer server's choice of key algorithms, but have not found a server-side setting that gets around putty's error.

The OpenSSH client matching the failing Ubuntu server version reports *"kex protocol error: type 7 seq 73"* while the server reports *"debug1: Received SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED for 73"*. The OpenSSH client's default configuration is to not perform rekeying at all.

Based on all these datapoints, I am inferring the following:

- OpenSSH's rekey implementation is broken on some server versions, like 7.2, but rekeying is disabled by default and the problem is not visible.
- PuTTY implements rekeying more completely, but is not correctly detecting broken servers.

Some solutions:

- Enable *Connection/SSH/Bugs/Handles SSH-2 key re-exchange badly* (*"On"*) for affected connection profiles; PuTTY will confirm *"Remote bug prevents key re-exchange (timeout)"* in its event log.
- Find an unaffected server software version to update to.

To test what server software is affected, you can set PuTTY's *Connection/SSH/Kex/Max minutes before rekey* to something low like 1 to cause it to rekey every minute. The default is 60, which means connections typically fail after 1 hour.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  As this was an issue I dealt with about 2 years ago I cannot confirm if it is a solution, but really appreciate the information for anyone reading this post that has this issue in the future.